# Android: No KeyEvent on unfocusable view?

Tags: android, focus, keyevent

In my case, I'm required to intercept all key events before they are dispatched to target.  So I installed a KeyListener on every view or widget, Activity.onKey can't satisfy me in the case.

However, I found that if view (like RelativeLayout) is not focusable, it won't receive any KeyEvent. And I also got following warnings

> WARN/KeyCharacterMap(312): No keyboard for id 0
>   WARN/KeyCharacterMap(312): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin

If I forced view to be focusable, it's going to receive KeyEvent. I'm curious about this phenomenon. I've no idea about if system never sends KeyEvents to view which is unfocusable or just I used wrong way to intercept key events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this use `dispatchKeyEvent` (see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.Callback.html#dispatchKeyEvent%28android.view.KeyEvent%29) on the Activity. This should receive every KeyEvent. You can do any modifications and then call `super.dispatchKeyEvent` if you want the standard processing to kick in.

Comment: It should work, but I don't want to intercept all key events of entire Activity, just a ViewGroup inside Activity. I can't tell if it's that ViewGroup in dispatchKeyEvent. For the time being, I'd like to try setting all views focusable, but I don't know if it has side effect. Looks like it's impossible to intercept all key events on ViewGroup level.

Comment: Well, is your desire not to intercept all events for performance reasons or because you're worried you'll interfere with default behavior? If you call `super.dispatchKeyEvent` for all events for the Views you are not interested in you'll get the default behavior, and performance shouldn't be an issue (unless you have someone typing REALLY REALLY REALLY fast :)).

Comment: Not for performance issue, just design purpose. Maybe I didn't make myself quit clear, I just wanna monitor one ViewGroup inside activity. I understood your idea. Thanks.