# How to make onKeyDown invoke no matter the focus?

Tags: android, focus, android-studio-2.1

I figured out that onKeyDown() calls on the view that is currently selected. Is there a way to make my activity catch the event no matter the focus?

My class if interested:

```
MaterialFilePicker filePicker;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Start File Picker
    filePicker = new MaterialFilePicker();
    filePicker.withActivity(this)
            .withRequestCode(1)
            .withHiddenFiles(true) // Show hidden files and folder
            .start();

    //Let DataManager prepare the application
    DataManager.StartUp(this);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        DataManager.File = new File(data.getStringExtra(FilePickerActivity.RESULT_FILE_PATH));
        startActivity(new Intent(this, SectionChooserActivity.class));
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keycode, KeyEvent e) {
    //This method will never get called :/
    switch (keycode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU:
            Stuff();
            return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keycode, e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can implement [dispatchKeyEvent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#dispatchKeyEvent(android.view.KeyEvent)) which is called before `onKeyDown`.

Got it from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6093631/1028256